# A key relation in Di Francesco's book on Conformal Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

Recently I am reading Di Francesco's book Volume I on Conformal Field Theory. In order to reduce the number of fields in a correlator, the calculation of Operator Algebra is extremely important. To do this, equation (6.175), which is derived from (6.174), is necessary. The author writes in the book below equation 6.174: ([source](https://books.google.fr/books?id=keUrdME5rhIC&pg=PA182))

> Applying this relation (6.174) on the r.h.s of Eq. (6.169), we find
> $$\sum_p C_{p12}z^{h_p-2h}\bar{z}^{\bar{h}_p-2\bar{h}}L_n|z,h_p\rangle |\bar{z},\bar{h}_p\rangle=\\\sum_p C_{p12}z^{h_p-2h}\bar{z}^{\bar{h}_p-2\bar{h}}\left[(h_p+h(n-1))z^n+z^{n+1}\partial_z\right]|z,h_p\rangle |\bar{z},\bar{h}_p\rangle
> $$

But I still can not understand how 6.174 is applied to deduce this equation presented above. Nor can I understand why the holomorphic dimension h appears on the right hand side of this equation. Since this is very important for the discussion on the calculation of the Operator Algebra, I can not go on without an understanding of this.

Comment: It would be good if OP (or somebody else?) could try to make the question formulation self-contained, so one doesn't have to open Di Francesco's book to understand the question.

Comment: A [link](http://books.google.fr/books?id=keUrdME5rhIC&pg=PA182&lpg=PA182&dq=Di+Francesco+conformal+field+theory+%226.169%22&source=bl&ots=v2bP63dA-5&sig=5xEydnIVEgdP6Ei2ti9QHO-IUcI&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=3QKqUs-zCIWN0wX31IDgAg&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Di%20Francesco%20conformal%20field%20theory%20%226.169%22&f=false)...

Comment: Thanks @Trimok. Unfortunately Google book links are not the most reliable, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if there is not an error in the right hand side of $6.174$, where it would be more logic (to understand the following lines...) to have a $(n+1)h ~z^n$ term instead of $(n+1)h$.

If this hypothesis is correct (???), then it is just the application of the Lebnitz rule for derivatives, that is :

$z^{n+1}\partial_z (z^{h_p-2h} f(z)) \\
= z^{n+1} ((h_p-2h) z^{h_p-2h-1} f(z) + z^{h_p-2h} \partial_z f(z))
\\ = ((h_p-2h)z^n + z^{n+1} \partial_z) f(z)$

Here $f(z) = \phi(z)\phi(\bar z)|h_p\rangle |\bar h_p\rangle = |z, h_p\rangle |\bar z,\bar h_p\rangle$

So, starting from $6.174$, using the relation before, plus the decomposition in powers series $6.172$, you would find $6.175$

Comment: You are right about the second term on r.h.s of equation 6.174. From the standard definition of a primary field this term should be $(n+1)h z^n$ instead of $(n+1)h$. However, I am not sure how the author replaced $L_n \phi$ with $[L_n,\phi]$ in the second step in equation 6.174 ? This can be done for n>0, but for n<0, $L_n$ will not annihilate the state $|h,\bar{h}>$.